# How would I implement a change approval process for a Django model?

Tags: python, django

I have a model for which changes need to be approved by a user with a certain flag before they are seen by everybody. Making two different identical models is not an option, because the model has a many-to-many field referencing itself, which needs to be linked to both approved and non-approved entries.

I'm using Django 1.7. django-moderation looks like the best option, but it doesn't support manytomany relations. I've also tried django-gatekeeper which didn't work for me either.

Is there a library which supports many-to-many relationships?
If not, how would I go about doing this myself?

Comment: You can take a look at the [Model Auditing and History grid](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/), you might be able to incorporate one of those apps to achieve what you want, or use them as inspiration for your own implementation.

Comment: I wrote an approval app that should work in your case. You would need a field on monitored model to switch their visibility and manage M2M with that trick.
https://github.com/artscoop/django-approval

Comment: you could achieve this using django-moderation. look  this link if you want to know about https://django-moderation.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://viewflow.io/. This might be helpful for your use case or you can extend this to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would create another table (tablename_approval) with columns something like

approved    | boolean
approved_by | foreign key to user
timestamp   | timestamp

to track the state of each individual row.

You might want to consider an enum rather than boolean to track the difference between items which have not yet been approved versus those that were checked and intentionally not approved.

Comment: I don't just need to track new models, I also need to track changes to models that already exist and are approved.

Comment: You could create a parallel table: tablename_history with all the same columns (or at least the ones you care about) and an additional timestamp and foreign key. Every time you save the model it makes a copy to the parallel table referring back to the original. This can be accomplished by overloading the save operation.